# Let $a$ and $b$ belong to a group $G.$ Find an $x$ in $G$ such that $xabx^{-1}=ba.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $a$ and $b$ belong to a group $G$. Find an $x$ in $G$ such that $xabx^{-1}= ba$.

This is what I have done so far, but I am stuck and not sure if I am in the right direction:

$xabx^{-1} = ba$

Multiply both sides on the right by $x$.

$xabx^{-1}x = bax$.

Now the $x^{-1}x$ cancel out: $xab = bax$.

This is where I am stuck because I am not sure how to solve for an $x$ in $G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try letting $x = a^{-1}$, so that $x^{-1} = (a^{-1})^{-1} = a$.

Or, if you prefer, let $x = b$, so $x^{-1} = b^{-1}$.

(Since $a, b \in G$, so are $a^{-1}, b^{-1} \in G$, since $G$ is a group and a group is closed under taking inverses.)

Comment: Now I completely understand. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Note, it also works for $x = b$

Comment: Yes, I did. I added it to my homework notes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

$x=a^{-1}$ or $x=b.$

Proof: $xabx^{-1}=ba.$ By a little manipulation we get $xa=b(ax)b^{-1.}$ Now as $x,a,b$ are in $G$ and the structure of the equation is similar to the one in question, we get by comparing the two as $x=b.$ Similarly, $bx^{-1}=a^{-1}(x^{-1}b)a.$ So by comparison again we get $x^{-1}=a$ or $x=a^{-1}.$

Answer (score -1):

If I put $~X = b~$ or $~X = a^{-1} ~$(consider as self inverse)than what we get

I get that the term     $~xabx^{-1} = ba ~$, become   $~ ba = ba~$

Which gives that it is satisfied.

As my opinion

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).